# PHP Real Time chat with Ratchet Websockets

Tags: php, websocket, wamp, zeromq, ratchet

I'm a beginner in PHP Websockets and I'm trying to create real-time chat with database storage. I was doing pretty good, but now I'm standing at one problem. There's problem, **when user1 sends message to user2 and user2 came to the site first (reload first on localhoste), it won't be "real-time".**

Let me explain it further.

Here's my **server.php**. It is practicly the same as ratchet tutorial:

```
$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();    
$pusher = new \Pusher();
$context = new React\ZMQ\Context($loop);
$pull = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
$pull->bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555'); // Binding to 127.0.0.1 means the only client that can connect is itself
$pull->on('message', array($pusher, 'onBlogEntry'));
$webSock = new React\Socket\Server($loop);
$webSock->listen(8080, '0.0.0.0'); // Binding to 0.0.0.0 means remotes can connect
$webServer = new Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
        new Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
        new Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
        new Ratchet\Wamp\WampServer($pusher ))), $webSock);
$loop->run();
```

In **pusher.php** are most important these methods (I omitted other non-important stuff):

```
protected $subscribedTopics = array();
protected $myID = array();

public function onSubscribe(ConnectionInterface $conn, $data) { 
    $this->subscribedTopics[json_decode($data)->teamID] = $data;
    $this->myID[json_decode($data)->userID] = $data;    
}

public function onBlogEntry($entry) {
    $entryData = json_decode($entry, true);

    if ((!array_key_exists($entryData['team_id'], $this->subscribedTopics)) ||
            (!array_key_exists($entryData['to_user_id'], $this->myID))
    ) {
        return;
    }

    $teamID = $this->subscribedTopics[$entryData['team_id']];
    $teamID->broadcast($entryData);   
}
```

In my **presenter Class** I have simple form. When user submits this form, this code follows:

```
$this->chatPartner = $values['to_user_id'];       //this I get from the form
$this->redrawControl('msg');                      //here I redraw my layout
$this->messages_model->addMessage($values);       //here I send data to database
$context = new \ZMQContext();
$socket = $context->getSocket(\ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH, 'my pusher');
$socket->connect("tcp://localhost:5555");
$socket->send(json_encode($values));
```

Then, in **view** I have this JavaScript code:

```
var myJSON = '{'
            + '"teamID" : {$teamId},'     //this I get from the presenter
            + '"userID"  : {$userId}'     //this I get from the presenter
            + '}'; 
var conn = new ab.Session('ws://localhost:8080',
       function() {
            conn.subscribe(myJSON, function(topic, data) { 
             if (data.from_user_id == mypartnerIdA) {                     
                         //here I edit the DOM
                     }  
                });
            },
            function() {
                console.warn('WebSocket connection closed');
            },
            {'skipSubprotocolCheck': true}
    );
```

**So, back to my problem**. I simulate 2 users. User1 reloads this page, where is javascript connection first. User2 reloads this page after him. When User1 sends a message to user2, message appers immediatly (real-time). But when user2 sends a message to user1, this message doesn't appear immediatly - it appears only after next reload of the page.

**And my question is** - How to fix this? How to make user2's message real-time, too? How can I fix this my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a misunderstanding of what the data yous end to subscribe is.
It is meant to use for ID's of chat sessions.

for example:

- A has a chat with B (chatId = 1)
- B has a chat with C (chatId = 2)
- C has a chat with A (chatId = 3)
- A, B and C are in one chat (chatId = 4)

  ```
  var chatId = 2; //this chat is only between users B and C
  conn.subscribe( chatId , function(topic, data) {
      ...
  }
  ```

The easiest way for me to understand it was by comparing it to a hashtag on twitter.
Each hashtag is in your case a chatId.
And for each subscription to a hashtag/chatId. You will have a WebSocket connection so that you receive all the updates for it.

This will be an easier way to do this in the long run then by having subdivided connections for a userId parameter.
It can also easily be stored in a database so that you know whom to send the messages to and who not.

Comment: Man, thank you very much, I didn't believe, that somebody help me here :))

Comment: no problem, if you need more information please let me know